# Having jpg and gif handled by IsapiModule in IIS7

Tags: iis-7

I'm struggling to get my HttpHandler to process requests for jpg and gifs.

I've gone to the website's Handler Mappings and added the following line:

```
Path: *.jpg,*.gif
State: Enabled
Path Type: Unspecified (I've also tried setting this to File)
Handler: IsapiModule
Entry Type: Local
```

Running through Visual Studio works, so I know its not my code. It also works on IIS6.

I've tried setting the app up in both classic and integrated mode.

Here's the appropriate Handler mappings specified in the web.config:

```
<add name="*.jpg,*.gif_*" path="*.jpg,*.gif" verb="*" type="ThumbnailGenerator,Utilities" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />    
<add name="JPEG-GIF" path="*.jpg,*.gif" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
```

Comment: 1. Do you get any errors or is your HttpHandler & HttpModule just being ignored? 2. Do the images still render?

Comment: I have my HttpModule logging to the DB as soon as it is called, and this is working locally, but live it is never logging, so I'm led to believe it is not being called. Images are still rendered, yes.

Comment: On your dev box, are you testing this against IIS or the built in Cassini web server?

Comment: Cassini, so the point is the HttpModule itself appears to be working: the problem is that IIS is not sending the request for jpgs and gifs to the module.

Comment: I had this working on IIS6 too. It doesn't work on either the production IIS7 or the dev server IIS7.

Comment: Actually its an HttpHandler that I can't get to work, not an HttpModule... sorry got confused.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by clearing out the handlers from web.config, then manually adding the using IIS: [Handler Mappings] -> [Add managed handler]

I'm not sure what difference this made, because the web.config looks pretty much the same as I had setup before, but now it works.